# Android Google Maps API V2 gets slower each time it loads again

Tags: android, performance, google-maps, android-fragments, google-maps-android-api-2

I have a fragment in my app which has a MapFragment inside.
When I load this fragment I start to read about 2000 marker data from server and after reading them I will loop through each marker and add it to the Map.
At first it takes 4 seconds for the map to show these 2000 markers. but each time after loading the map again ( like changing orientation or changing the drawermenu item and backing to the map again ) it takes more and more to load the markers. for example after 8 times changing the orientation, it takes 40 seconds for the map to load the same 2000 markers !

here is how I initialize the map :

```
        googleMap = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
        CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder().target( new LatLng(50.941303, 6.958166)).zoom(10).build();
        googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));

        // check if map is created successfully or not
        if (googleMap == null) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),
                    "Sorry! unable to create maps", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show();
        }
```

and here I add the markers to the map :

```
    for (int i = 0; i<mapVehicles.size(); i++)
    {
        // latitude and longitude
        double latitude = mapVehicles.get(i).latitude;
        double longitude = mapVehicles.get(i).longitude;

        // create marker
        MarkerOptions marker = new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(latitude, longitude))
                .title(mapVehicles.get(i).lineTripIdentification).snippet(destinationShort + ": " + mapVehicles.get(i).destination);

        // Changing marker icon
        marker.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.vehicleannotation));

        // adding marker            
        vehicleMarkers.put(googleMap.addMarker(marker), mapVehicles.get(i));


    }
```

I also used the following in the onCreateView of the Fragment which has the MapFragment :

```
this.setRetainInstance(true);
```

any help would be much appreciated :)

Comment: Do you add the markers again each time?

Comment: yes. because the position of the markers are changing continuously and also if I don't add them each time then the map just loads and I don't have any marker on the map.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of removing and adding all markers again and again you should change the position of each marker by setPosition (LatLng latlng).

Answer (score 0):

Only load the markes if not loaded before:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    ...

    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        // do nothing 
    } else {
        // add markers
    }

}
```

Comment: the position of the markers are changing continuously and I need to add them each time the map loads.

Comment: In that case you must remember to clear the map in betweeen. Also, you could consider only adding the visible markers to decrease the amount of CPU cycles and memory used https://code.google.com/p/android-maps-extensions/

Comment: I use clear() method on the google map instance whenever I am trying to add the markers at fist but it seems it doesn't help much and I have the problem even with clearing the map.